# Sails / Waterline model help - how can I store data that might be an array, json or string?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm storing user input into MongoDB with Sails / Waterline and because the type of field is dependent on their setup I'm finding it difficult to figure out the best way to store the data.

The **'surveyField'** model is like:

```
// SURVEY FORM FIELD DEFINITIONS

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    constraints: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['none', 'unique', 'combo', 'same'],
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: 'none'
    },
    isRequired: {
      type: 'boolean',
      required: true,
      defaultsTo: false
    },
    attributeType: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['boolean', 'text', 'localizedText', 'enum', 'localizedEnum', 'number', 'money', 'date', 'time', 'dateTime'],
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

The user will have added any number of these fields to their form and so their form will contain a reference to the types of fields they have chosen. When their form is built I know exactly how to handle/display each of the fields based on this information, but saving the info is proving to be somewhat difficult because that Model needs to assume a type for the value field.

The **'surveyData'** model looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    value: {
      **type: 'string' // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS**
    },
    surveyFieldType: {
      model: 'surveyFieldType',
      required: true
    },
    survey: {
      model: 'survey',
      required: true
    },
    user: {
      model: 'user',
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

The issue occurs when the value might be a string or it might be json... or any of the other ['standard data types.'](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/data-types-attributes.md)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

** **EDIT** **

I'll also need this value to be searchable as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change it a little. And deal with survery answer as more complex value than just a value. Change type to JSON & build custom validator.

```
attributes: {
    value: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
```

and make it lake that

```
{
    surveyFieldType: something,
    value: {
        type: 'Array', 
        value: [1,2,3]
    },
    survey: survey,
    user: user
}
```

You can search now by that, you have flattened types of all replies. Based on value.type you can create custom validation rules for json.